# The import org.springframework.boot.test cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am currently working on a Spring application using SpringBoot. To manage depedencies of this project, I'm using Gradle.

I wanted to implement some tests but I got this error: "The import org.springframework.boot.test cannot be resolved".

Here is the code.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class ClassTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

And the content of the build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "com.moowork.gulp" version "1.2.0"rk.node" version "1.2.0"
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.1.5.RELEASE"
    id "java"
}
configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    developmentOnly "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"


    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"
    implementation "nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect"

    testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2"

    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok"
    implementation "org.projectlombok:lombok"

    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.1"

    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.0"
}
```

The simplified stack trace is the following:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The import org.springframework.boot.test cannot be resolved
The import org.springframework.test cannot be resolved
SpringRunner cannot be resolved to a type
Class<SpringRunner> cannot be resolved to a type
SpringBootTest cannot be resolved to a type

at climenvi.webapp.ClassTest.<init>(ClassTest.java:12)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried some solutions found already for this but nothing corrected the problem. Could you help me please ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you provide the full stacktrace to see what is raising the exception?

Comment: Added to the post

Comment: it looks like you are missing some dependencies in your classpath, specifically the test dependencies

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of your problems, but you need the junit-jupiter-engine dependency to run JUnit 5 tests.